# Add a new service to scrapyd from current project

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapyd

I want to create a custom service for scrapyd, from the scrapy project but I keep getting error.

I created `crawler/webservice.py`:

```
from scrapyd.webservice import WsResource


class BackInTime(WsResource):
    def render_GET(self, txtrequest):
        return {
            'id': 'something works!'
        }
```

and then modified `scrapyd.conf` and added the line `backintime.json = crawler.webservice.BackInTime` under `[services]` tag.

Bu when I run the command `scrapyd` I keep getting the error:

```
...
  File "c:\personal\virtualenvs\crawlie\lib\site-packages\scrapyd\app.py", line 39, in application
    webservice = TCPServer(http_port, server.Site(webcls(config, app)), interface=bind_address)
  File "c:\personal\virtualenvs\crawlie\lib\site-packages\scrapyd\website.py", line 33, in __init__
    servCls = load_object(servClsName)
  File "c:\personal\virtualenvs\crawlie\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 46, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked

builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crawler'


Failed to load application: No module named 'crawler'
```

Tried to follow some previous solutions but without any success:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/scrapy-users/webservice/scrapy-users/czu8YeYFvao/8GDHMJbi56wJ
- [How to add a new service to scrapyd from current project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369470/how-to-add-a-new-service-to-scrapyd-from-current-project)
- [Implementing own scrapyd service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950416/implementing-own-scrapyd-service)

How should I add the new service so scrapyd can import it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the import module of your app to the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. In my `Dockerfile` it looks like this:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:${APPDIR}/${APPNAME}"
```

On your local machine it might look like:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/app/crawler"
```

After that, run Scrapyd.